# VPN gets disconnected when using WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, vpn, router

I've Huawei DG8045 VDSL router, when I'm connected over its wifi my VPN gets disconnected after few minutes but when I'm connected using lan cable I can use my VPN connection normally.
I tried to disable the router firewall but the problem still exist.
I've tried another router (old ADSL2 BILLION router) and I can connect to VPN normally whether using wifi or lan cable. 
Any ideas what can I do?

Comment: Missed to say that when using WiFi internet connection is good, speed is over 20 Mbps (using speedtest.net)

Comment: Internet speeds don't take anything like packet loss into account, so you'll need to do additional tests to check the quality of the connection.

Comment: I think ping and jitter numbers are also good, with 0 % packet loss

Comment: Ping is 8 ms and jitter is 4 ms

Answer (score 0):

Fixing channel to 11 instead of Auto in my router WLAN settings solved my issue. Now I can connect to VPN successfully over WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your router on Auto WLAN setting try to fix channel on 11, or another. This will solve my problem in just few minutes. Restart your router than try it :)

Comment: Thanks, this worked with me yesterday. However, today my VPN connection keeps going down again .. I changed channel back to auto then VPN connected for a while.. I think this is still not the root cause of the issue.